# dynamically generate html tables with row spans/nests

Tags: python, html, dataframe, html-table

I want to create HTML tables from Python dataframes to generate email reports.

I want to be able to dynamically generate these tables and group things by setting different rowspans to aggregate on different columns.Where users are able to choose a column they want to group the data on.

I am able to do this fairly easily when grouping by one column. But say when I want to do it on two columns such as below for the Code and CCY columns:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLuf6.jpg

```
<html>
   <table cellpadding="4" style="border: 1px solid #000000; border-collapse: collapse;" border="1">
      <tr>
      <thead>
         <th>Code</th>
         <th>Total # of Entries</th>
         <th>A</th>
         <th>B</th>
         <th>Description</th>
         <th>Ccy</th>
         <th>Date 1</th>
         <th>Date 2</th>
         <th>Px_chg_pct</th>
      </thead>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>ABC</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>4405</td>
         <td>3B1070</td>
         <td>TEXT</td>
         <td>USD</td>
         <td>1109</td>
         <td>1108</td>
         <td>0.2415</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td rowspan=3>DEF</td>
         <td rowspan='3'>3</td>
         <td>6490</td>
         <td>17878</td>
         <td>CURRENCY EXCHANGE</td>
         <td rowspan=2>CAD</td>
         <td>11.6</td>
         <td>7.9</td>
         <td>-0.5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td colspan>C036490</td>
         <td>U78</td>
         <td>CURRENCY EXCHANGE1</td>
         <td>20.57</td>
         <td>27.9</td>
         <td>-0.2625</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td colspan>C036490</td>
         <td>31B3078</td>
         <td>CURRENCY EXCHANGE</td>[enter image description here][1]
         <td>USD</td>
         <td>0.57</td>
         <td>2.1</td>
         <td>-0.25</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</html>
```

I'm having some trouble doing this.

My logic currently is to locate the aggregator columns and create a total column after that aggregator index, and sort of 'hard coding' it. Please excuse the quality as I drew it up quickly.

```
def add_data_rows_to_tables(html_code,pivot_pos,length,style,aggregate_on):
if length == 1:
    html_code += row_start + style + '>'
    for index, row in pivot_pos.iterrows():
        for all in pivot_pos.columns.tolist():
            html_code += '<td>%s</td>' % row[all]
    html_code += row_end

else:
    html_code += row_start + style + '>'
    first = pivot_pos.iloc[0]
    for all in pivot_pos.columns.tolist():
        if all != aggregate_on and all != 'Total for %s'%aggregate_on:
            html_code += '<td>%s</td>' % first[all]
        if all == aggregate_on:
            html_code += '<td rowspan=%d>%s</td>' % (length, pivot_pos[aggregate_on].iloc[0])
        if all == 'Total for %s'%aggregate_on:
            html_code += '<td rowspan=%d>%s</td>' % (length, length)
        if all == 'Ccy':
            html_code += '<td rowspan=%d>%s</td>' % (length, length)

    html_code += row_end

    for i in range(1,length):
        html_code += row_start + style + '>'
        for all in pivot_pos.columns.tolist():
            if all != aggregate_on and all != 'Total for %s'%aggregate_on:
                html_code += '<td>%s</td>' % pivot_pos[all].iloc[i]
        html_code += row_end
return html_code
```

However this doesn't really work well when adding multiple columns to aggregate/span on, and I have trouble making the correct recursive call since the spans have to be set in advance (or maybe I'm misunderstanding).

Please let me know if you guys have any tips on doing this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using `to_html` function of pandas and also explain why it does not fit your purpose.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html

Comment: I can't seem to find much resources on using to_html when trying to nest and aggregate specific columns. I want to be able to specific the wrapping and row/col spans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what I will try to do is to preprocess/precompute the possible nests and their corresponding rowspan values into a matrix for each categories combinations.
And then when creating the table, look up the rowspans for each row of data perhaps.